# htaccess rule issue in redirecting the url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to redirect all below pattern url to before "?" url
i.e

```
Xyz.com/worksheet/rebus/?random=testing11
Xyz.com/worksheet/rebus/?abc
Xyz.com/worksheet/rebus/?l=1
```

should be redirected to

```
Xyz.com/worksheet/rebus/
```

I tried many things but not able to succeed. How can i do using .htaccess

Rules tried

```
RewriteBase /worksheet/
RewriteRule ^rebus/?$ /worksheet/rebus/ [L,R=301]
```

Overall

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /worksheet/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(rebus)/\?(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  /worksheet/%1/ [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^rebus/?$ /worksheet/rebus [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?url=$2&tableName=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?url=$2&tableName=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?url=$2&tableName=$1&showSol=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you

Comment: Thanks for doing so. You are hitting Xyz.com/worksheet/rebus/?random=testing11 link in browser? If yes then from which file in backend it should get served?

Comment: Man i need a rule of redirect using .htaccess, it not dependend on backend

Comment: I get that, but every page/Uri can rewrite itl on backend to some file like index.php or index.html. like that is there any file which your URL should print out?

Comment: I jjust dont want paramters to be passed i.e /worksheet/rebus/?abc to worksheet/rebus/

Answer (score 1):

Have it this way:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /worksheet/

# \?\S matches at least one character after ?
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(worksheet/rebus)/\?\S [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^rebus/?$ /worksheet/rebus? [L,R=301,NC]

# skip all rules for real files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$2&tableName=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$2&tableName=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$2&tableName=$1&showSol=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Not working solution, going for infinite redirect

Comment: Did you try clearing browser cache? What URL did you use to test? Are there more rules?